# android animation current frame sync with touch position

Tags: android, animation, touch

I want to animate some of view's when a `BottomSheet` is scrolling up/down(or anything like `BottomSheet`) but i want to animation stop when user stop moving touch .

in other words I want to animation current frame depends on touch position.

I have searched a lot about animations but I found nothing that can help me

I want to know is there any library or some code that can help me or i have to do this all by my self?

**edit**

what I'm trying to implement is exactly like [this](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/music-player-4f31a2fc-84a2-4c3a-9ff0-aeb540c8fcb8)

Comment: Show, don't tell. As per [ask], show us a [mcve] that illustrates what you want to do and what you have tried, and then show the results.

Comment: @jvd ok i'll edit soon